# SQL Server 2012: Select results not equal to string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have users and roles.  And this is a part of my query:

```
(select R.RoleName from [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] as R 
    join [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] as UR on R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
    join [dbo].[aspnet_Users] as U on UR.UserId = U.Userid
    where U.UserName = 'User1') <> 'Doctor'
```

But because a user can have multiple roles (in this case `User1` is `Doctor` and `Client`) I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How I can make it work so the query will return the roles of the users that neither of their roles are `Doctor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] Rsq 
                       JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] URsq ON Rsq.RoleId = URsq.RoleId
                       JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] Usq ON UR.UserId = Usq.Userid
                  WHERE Usq.UserName = [Outside Query User ID Field]
                    AND Rsq.RoleName = 'Doctor')
```

Comment: well that worked but why you use this line : `Usq.UserName = [Outside Query User ID Field]` instead of  `U.UserName = 'User1`

Comment: I wasn't sure what tables you would be referencing outside of the SubQuery (and the Alias's). In case you were referencing the same table(s) in the main query, I put the suffix `sq` on the Alias (sq meaning subquery). This means you could freely use the Alias `R`,  `U` and `UR` in your main `FROM` clause. hope that helps explain. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong way. Try this

```
 ; WITH CTE AS 
(
    select DISTINCT U.UserName, R.RoleName from [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] as R 
    join [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] as UR on R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
    join [dbo].[aspnet_Users] as U on UR.UserId = U.Userid
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE CIN WHERE CIN.UserName = CTE.UserName AND CIN.RoleName = 'Doctor')
```

Comment: That won't work. If someone is a Client And Doctor, then a row for them as a Client will still return. The OP wants the User to be completely omitted if they are a Doctor (regardless of other roles).

Comment: Ok got it. Use NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated my query. Try it and let me know in case you get any error.